# Find the package names from a function name in R

Tags: r, function, package, cran

Sometimes, I got some R code without the information of loaded packages. For example,

```
x <- thisisafunction(data)
```

and I have no idea which package `thisisafunction` is coming from. I want to find all packages which contain `thisisafunction` function in CRAN. This package may or may not have been installed in the current machine. Is it possible to do this? I tried googling the package name, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: `library(sos); findFn("thisisafunction")`

Comment: @Roland I guess the OP is seeing code snippets where the preamble/package-loading part is missing. If so, yours is the only correct answer so far... +1 to the question and comment; neat package.

Comment: @Roland - you should put that as an answer

Comment: Well @Roland is close but it is (strictly speaking) not an answer either as OP already mentioned Google, and dismisses it. `sos` is "merely" a constrained Google Search.  The question is ultimately unanswerable for random snippets of code.

Comment: note that there's more R packages than those on CRAN. There's rforge, r-forge, bioC, github, bitbucket, googlecode, etc.