# Which function does R call to print output to console (e. g. for sessionInfo)?

Tags: r

I was trying to store the pretty-printed (formatted) output of `sessionInfo` in a character variable and have found a solution using `pretty.si <-capture.output(sessionInfo())` which results in a vector of character strings (one element per line).

Just out of curiosity:

Which function is called by R to get the pretty-printed output (e. g. I couldn't find a S3 `print.sessionInfo` function)?

If I look into the implementation of `sessionInfo` it just returns the unformatted result as list of lists or vectors:

```
> sessionInfo
function (package = NULL) 
{
    z <- list()
    z$R.version <- R.Version()
    z$platform <- z$R.version$platform
    # ... omitted code ...
    class(z) <- "sessionInfo"
    z
}
```

**Edit 1: BTW - To create a pretty-printed string from `sessionInfo()` you can use:**

```
si <- capture.output(print(sessionInfo()))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does actually have an S3 method, it's just not exported from the package namespace which would be the `utils` package.

If you look through the output of the methods search you will see an asterix next to the sessionInfo method, which the documentation says is:

> The S3 method name is followed by an asterisk * if the method
>   definition is not exported from the package namespace in which the
>   method is defined.

```
> x = methods("print")
> x[x == "print.sessionInfo"]
[1] "print.sessionInfo"
```

therefore to see the code of the method you can do

```
utils:::print.sessionInfo
```

Comment: Great! How did you find out the package that `print.sessionInfo` is hidden in?

Comment: `?sessionInfo` says it at the top next to the function name in { }.

Comment: or you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696431/how-to-get-the-package-name-of-a-function-in-r